# xml validator validate API's design

Tags: java, api-design, xml-validation

I'm planning to write a validator method and was looking around to see the best ways to implement it. I came across javax.xml.validation.Validator Class. It has a [method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/validation/Validator.html#validate(javax.xml.transform.Source,%20javax.xml.transform.Result))

> abstract void validate(Source source, Result result)

which validates the specified input and send the augmented validation result to the specified output.

Is it a good name for the validate method? Since, it's not just validating but also populating the result field. 
Or better design is to return the result

> abstract Result validate(Source source)

or call the method as

> abstract void  validateAndPopulateResult(Source source, Result result)?

Answer (score 0):

For API design, I think you were right to look at what already exists.

If I were writing an implementation of an Xml Validator then I'd probably extend that `javax.xml.validation.Validator`.

But even if I'm writing some other kind of document Validator, I might still follow the convention of the `javax.xml.validation` API. I'd use the same method signatures of that `Validator`, and use similar method function and documentation but for the specific case of whatever I'm validating.

In short, my vote is for:

```
public void validate(Source source, Result result) throws ???Exception, IOException;
```

and

```
public void validate(Source source) throws ???Exception, IOException;
```